# Вывести данные из двух таблиц

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть две таблицы:

Таблица грузов (traffic): номер записи(id), контейнер(container), ссылка на клиента(id_client), ссылка на менеджера(id_manager),  дата фактического прибытия груза(arriving_date).

[image: Таблица traffic]

Таблица клиентов (clients): номер записи(id),  название компании(name), ИНН(INN), адрес(address), почта(mail), телефон(phone).

[image: Таблица clients]

Необходимо вывести количество грузов у каждого клиента. У одного клиента может быть несколько грузов. Правильно ли я понимаю, что это надо делать с помощью сводных таблиц? Если не сложно подскажите хотя бы набросок запроса.

Comment: *Правильно ли я понимаю, что это надо делать с помощью сводных таблиц?* Скорее нет, чем да. Думаю, нужны обычные JOIN, GROUP BY и SUM().

Comment: Вяжите грузы и компании  traffic.id_client = clients.id, агрегируете с помощью count(traffic.id) и группируете по clients.id. Запрос все же напишите сами.

Answer (score 0):

Про сводные не понял на самом деле, что вы хотели, но кажется этот запрос решает вашу проблему

```
select cl.id, count(distinct gr.id_container)
from clients cl left join traffic gr on cl.id = gr.id_client
group by cl.id
```

count(distinct gr.id_container) это может быть необязательно, я прост не уверен в ваших данных, если traffic хранит только уникальные id грузов то можно **count(1)**

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. id_container?

Comment: Если грузы у вас уникальное поле то можно count(1) вместо count(distinct gr.id_container)

Comment: не уникальное поле

Comment: Тогда count(distinct gr.id_container)

Comment: Спасибо! Все получилось